# Python/Pandas –– ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected x fields in line i, saw y

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need some help. I am using the following code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display
with open (r'C:\Users\Michel Spiero\Desktop\Analise Python Optitex\Analytics Optitex\base_entrada_python_v2.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV =csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')

entrada_arquivo = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Michel Spiero\Desktop\Analise Python Optitex\Analytics Optitex\base_entrada_python_v2.csv')
entrada_arquivo.head(10)
```

Then I get this error:

```
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-248d3ffc3e4b> in <module>()
      3     readCSV =csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
      4 
----> 5 entrada_arquivo = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Michel Spiero\Desktop\Analise Python Optitex\Analytics Optitex\base_entrada_python_v2.csv')
      6 entrada_arquivo.head(10)
      7 

C:\Users\Michel Spiero\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    653                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    654 
--> 655         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    656 
    657     parser_f.__name__ = name

C:\Users\Michel Spiero\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    409 
    410     try:
--> 411         data = parser.read(nrows)
    412     finally:
    413         parser.close()

C:\Users\Michel Spiero\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
    980                 raise ValueError('skipfooter not supported for iteration')
    981 
--> 982         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
    983 
    984         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):

C:\Users\Michel Spiero\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1717     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1718         try:
-> 1719             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   1720         except StopIteration:
   1721             if self._first_chunk:

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:10862)()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:11138)()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:11884)()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:11755)()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:28765)()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 9 fields in line 3, saw 11
```

My goal is to get this CSV file (which is separated by ;) and import it in to a data frame.

It is important to say that the numbers are defined in the portuguese format so, the decimals are separated by comma and not by a dot.

Can someone help me? It is a basic question but I am sutck.

Comment: Was your question addressed? Can you please close it and accept an answer  if it was? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [CSV file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxldpL96JXidaklRUFdNdVBPdlk/view?usp=sharing) needs a little parsing to handle the quotes. A regex separator followed by a `dropna` operation should do it.

```
path = r'C:\Users\Michel Spiero\Desktop\Analise Python Optitex\Analytics Optitex\base_entrada_python_v2.csv'

with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    entrada_arquivo = pd.read_csv(f, sep=';|"', engine='python')\
                                               .dropna(how='all', axis=1)
```

---

```
entrada_arquivo.head(5)

   Cliente  Numero           N Fantasia  Serie Docto.  Loja  Data Saida  \
0     1293   47367                  NaN             1     1     42009.0   
1     1293   47367                  NaN             1     1     42009.0   
2    15043   47368  OTICA DE RESPLENDOR             1     1     42010.0   
3    15043   47368  OTICA DE RESPLENDOR             1     1     42010.0   
4    15043   47368  OTICA DE RESPLENDOR             1     1     42010.0   

                                      Nome  DT Emissao Tipo da nota  \
0  DUBLATEX MC COM DE ART VIAG E CAL LTDAE       42009            B   
1  DUBLATEX MC COM DE ART VIAG E CAL LTDAE       42009            B   
2            FRANCISMAR CORREA LOURENCO ME       42009            N   
3            FRANCISMAR CORREA LOURENCO ME       42009            N   
4            FRANCISMAR CORREA LOURENCO ME       42009            N   

   Cond. Pagto   ...      Total Vendedor 1.1 Vendedor 2  Data Saida.1  \
0            1   ...     2204,1          NaN        NaN       42009.0   
1            1   ...    1598,42          NaN        NaN       42009.0   
2          322   ...      173,8         65.0        NaN       42010.0   
3          322   ...     245,85         65.0        NaN       42010.0   
4          322   ...      491,7         65.0        NaN       42010.0   

   Vlr.Bruto Vlr.ICMS Estado.1 Cond. Pagto.1 Volume 1 Transp.  
0    3802,52        0       SP             1        1      43  
1    3802,52        0       SP             1        1      43  
2    3638,02   397,58       MG           322        6       5  
3    3638,02   397,58       MG           322        6       5  
4    3638,02   397,58       MG           322        6       5  

[5 rows x 39 columns]
```

Comment: Didn,t work. I got this error:  UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
..........................
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 146: invalid start byte

Comment: @user1922364 Post a sample of your CSV data in the question.

Comment: @user1922364 Your CSV was quoted, making things problematic. Take a look now.