# Reading a csv file with irregular number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to adjust some data but the raw data has for each row a different number of columns. I know there are some similar asked questions like

[Reading a CSV file with irregular number of columns using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66394939/reading-a-csv-file-with-irregular-number-of-columns-using-pandas) which almost describes my problem but in that case the user has a fix amount of maximum columns/rows. In my case I don't know the maximum number of columns (and in which line it is).

### structure of my dataset

The dataset (which you can find here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tXigrvlofn5paoB_-JvPt7Ent2ZNZmzmlk6FZHhzNSA/edit?usp=sharing) has a header line, but the header is useless and I won't import it. After the 8th column the following 6 columns repeat themselves continuously

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | car | - | - | 299.80 | 115.12 | etc. |
| 2 | Heavy Vehicle | - | - | 333.12 | 89.02 | etc. |

### 1st approach

With ([How to know CSV line count before loading in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46549078/how-to-know-csv-line-count-before-loading-in-python))

```
dataname = 'csv_file.csv'
lines = sum(1 for line in open(dataname))
```

I can count the number of rows without loading the csv in python but I haven't found a similar way to count the number of columns without loading the csv file.

### 2nd approach

I found another approach (which almost solves my issue) in [Python/Pandas –– ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected x fields in line i, saw y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46136143/python-pandas-parsererror-error-tokenizing-data-c-error-expected-x-fields) but I get an error

> pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1701 fields in line 3, saw 2829

when I am using pandas `data_raw2 = pd.read_csv(dataname, delimiter=';', decimal='.', header=0)`. The solution in this thread is to use the

```
with open(dataname, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    bla = pd.read_csv(f,  engine='python').dropna(how='all', axis=1)
```

but this returns a conjoined dataframe with the given number of rows but only one column (see picture below).

[image: given dataframe after using 2nd approach]

Comment: After 2nd approach you can do: `bla[0].str.split(';', expand=True)`

Comment: @Cyttorak that line raises the following error: raise `KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0`. Could it be caused because I am using python 3.8.6 version?

Comment: No, I assumed `0` to be the first column name. use `bla[bla.columns[0]]` instead of `bla[0]`

Comment: Thumbs up! That worked! Now I can continue trying to transpose and rearrange the array.

Comment: With a basic text read you can read the file line by line, splitting each, and collecting the results in a list of lists.  Once you've loaded all, you know the number of lines, and the maximum length of each.  Go back through the list, and expand each sublist as needed.  `np.genfromtxt` collects such a list of lists, and makes the array at the end.